# Why does Drupal webform civicrm returns DB Error: syntax error when trying to add a new organization type contact?

Tags: civicrm

I've setup a webform wherein all logged in users can create new organization contacts on civicrm via webform civicrm integration module. Not sure if this is a bug or I'm missing something important from the setup.

Note:
Current module and versions used.

Civicrm version 4.4

Webform civicrm integration version 7.x-4.9

Webform version 7.x-4.1

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a bugreport and should be solved in appropriate issue queue, not here.

Answer (score 5):

Might want to ensure that you are using the latest versions of all the above modules. There have been significant improvements in the newer releases

Also can the user create non-organization contacts? What is the error message?

lobo

Answer (score 5):

I found a similar question on the webform_civicrm issue queue: https://www.drupal.org/node/2356741 . If this is your question too, then based on the further information you provide there of the MySQL query and error message...

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY id1, id2 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + VALUES(weight)'"

... here's one possible explanation, if you are on a very old version of MySQL. The VALUES() function was added in MySQL 4.1.1. If you're on an older version than that, it would explain the syntax error.